# Do we have MySite details in webservice sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, my-site

Do we have My Site details available in web-service share point 2010.

@ David Lozzi: i want to fetch the data of "About me" using Web Service. I need to display the data in the DataView. 
Is there any web service which provide the Mysite details to display in Dataview.

Comment: what details? My Site is a site collection, so the web services that are available for your team sites are available on my sites....

Answer (score 1):

According to you later edit, you actually want to display information from the User Profile Services. "About me" is a field of the User Profile.

Yes, there is a webservice, which can return you User Profile data. It is located at `http://<site URL>/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550407%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is a code sample, which displays you all the User Profile properties. It assumes, that you have added the above web service as a *Web reference* to your Visual Studio project:

```
static void GetUserProfilePropertyData()
{
    UserProfileWebService.localhost.PropertyData[] properties = 
    myService.GetUserProfileByName("domainname\\username");
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Name);
        Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Value);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

But if your code runs on the Sharepoint farm, I think you should consider accessing the User Profile Service by the object model.

```
using ( SPSite site = new SPSite("site url"))
{
    ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
    UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
    UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(@"domainuser");
    // you got user profile object. now you can use any property of it.
    // I think for the AboutMe field it would be
    var aboutMe = profile["AboutMe"] as string;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Cheers!